# segmentation fault during execution

Tags: c, ansi-c

```
#include<stdio.h>   
int main()  
{    
    char *arg[10],*c;  
    int count=0;  
    FILE *fp,*fq;  
    printf("Name of the file:");  
    scanf("%s",arg[1]);  
    fp=fopen(arg[1],"w");  
    printf("\t\t%s",arg[1]);  
    printf("Input the text into the file\n");  
    printf("Press Ctrl+d to the stop\n");  
    while((*c=getchar())!=EOF)  
    {  
            fwrite(c,sizeof(char),1,fp);  
            count++;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: homework? No problem if it is. Just tag it so that you can get better answers

Comment: you could at least write something from yourself

Comment: You should really go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if all you do is post code

Comment: At least write something in your post that lets us know what your question is, instead of making us assume you are wanting to know why it is seg faulting.

Comment: *Sidenote:* Learn to use the debugger. At least enough to find out what line is throwing the error (for gcc on linux this would be `gdb program \n run \n [wait until it stops] bt \n`, other systems will differ but will still have this functionality). Then you might have figured it out for yourself, and would have been able to show us a shorter, clearer example code.

Comment: i am a starter to the c/c++ ,so please bare me for a period of time and this is my q.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line

```
char *arg[10],*c;
```

to

```
char arg[1000],c;
```

This line

```
scanf("%s",arg[1]);
```

to

```
scanf("%s",arg);
```

And this line

```
while((*c=getchar())!=EOF)
```

to

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
```

Explanation:

`char *c;` is not a character.  It's a *pointer* to a character.  It starts out just pointing to a random bit of memory, which will often be filled with random data - whatever was most recently written there.

`char c;` *is* a character.

The same thing applies to `char *arg[10]`.  It's an array of ten pointers.  They point into random memory, filled with random data.

Note: my change is *not* best practice.  If someone were to type in a filename 1000 characters or more long, you'd write over the end of the `arg` buffer.  Depending on what you're doing, this can be a security bug.

Comment: i have used char * so that 1 arg of the fwrite will have a pointer and i wnt to seek the file.I have made the necessary changes like *arg[]to arg[1000],char *c to char c but i am gettin till a segmentation fault .My intention is to reverse the contents of a file and paste it on another file .Above program is a bit of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *arg[10] ;
```

`arg` is array of char pointers. You need to assign them memory locations using `malloc` before taking input -

```
scanf("%s",arg[1]); // arg[1] is not assigned to point to any memory location
                    // and is what causing the segmentation fault.
```

So do -

```
arg[1] = malloc( stringLengthExpectedToEnter + 1 ) ; // +1 for termination character
```

Should do like that with the rest of array elements too (or) simply change `char*arg[10]` to `char arg[10]` and make sure to enter only enter 9 characters.

---

I think you are confusing between a **pointer** and **a normal variable**.

```
int *ptr;
```

`ptr` is variable that can hold the address of an integer variable. Memory is allocated to for `ptr` variable to hold an integer address. That's it. `ptr` is in an uninitalized state and is pointing no where (or) might be pointing to garbage. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer's behavior is undefined and you are lucky enough if it gives a **segmentation-fault**.

Now, you need to assign it a valid memory location using `malloc`.

```
ptr = malloc( sizeof(int) ) ; // Allocates number of bytes required to hold an
                              // integer and returns it's address.
```

So, `ptr` is now pointing to memory location acquired from free store that can hold an integer. Such acquired locations from free stored must be freed using `free`, else you have classical problem of **memory leak**. It is good practice to initialize pointer to **NULL** while declaration.

```
int *ptr = NULL ;
```

Hope it helps !

```
scanf("%d", ptr) ; // Notice that & is not required before ptr. Because ptr 
                   // content is address itself.
```

A **normal variable** story is entirely different. When declared -

```
int var ;
```

Memory is allocated to `var` to hold an integer. So, you can directly assign it an integer.

Comment: Good explanation but i have a doubt here.Is the memory of the pointer static or it stores permanently after the exiting the program( if i have not allocated memory to  it dynamically) and where is the memory stored like in command line args                  ex-                                                                 int main(argc ,*argv[])......

Answer (score 1):

In

```
char *arg[10];
```

you define an array of 10 pointers to char **but you do not initialize its elements**. arg[0], arg[1], ..., arg[9] will all have undefined values.

Then, you try to enter a string into one of those undefined values. Lucky you, you got a segmentation fault. Had you been unlucky, your program [could format your hard disk](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior) instead.

Comment: I don't see any wrong here. Why downvote ? Up voting to balance :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I wouldn't downvote for this, but "your program could format your hard disk instead" is over-egging things a bit...

Comment: Clever link notwithstanding, the compiler can generate all the code it likes, there's no modern OS that is going to let it format the HD.  I stick with over-egging.

Comment: @Jon: I'll try and remember to use my other UB example in the future ... **make the computer ooze lemon juice from the USB port**

Comment: @pmg I actually prefer that one.  Conveys the point more succinctly :-)

Comment: @Jon: In systems without protected memory "could format the hard drive" *is* possible, though admittedly of low probability. Admittedly this class does not include any general purpose consumer machines anymore.

Comment: @dmckee, I'm well aware of that - but fewer and fewer people are running DOS, or AmigaOS, or Linux on a 68000. Hence "modern OS". If you count the stack in something like Arduino as an OS, it's still possible in those sorts of places.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>   
int main()  
{    
   char arg[10],c;  
   int count=0;  
   FILE *fp;  
   printf("Name of the file:");  
   scanf("%s",arg);  
   fp=fopen(arg,"w");  
   printf("\t\t%s",arg);  
   printf("Input the text into the file\n");  
   printf("Press Ctrl+d to the stop\n");  
   while((c=getchar())!=EOF)  
   {  
        fwrite(&c,sizeof(char),1,fp);  
        count++;  
   }

   if(fp != NULL){
      fclose(fp);
      fp = NULL;
   }
   return 0;  
}
```